# How to get JobQueue and JobDefinition name in Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

In a Cloudformation template, how can I can I get a Batch::JobDefinition and Batch::JobQueue name, so I can pass them into a Lambda as a variable?

I have tried pulling it out with `!GetAtt` using `JobQueueName` `name` `QueueName` but it all fails on updating the stack. Using `!Ref` only gives me the arn, which I can't use in the JS SDK to communicate with the batch processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both resources, [AWS::Batch::JobQueue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-batch-jobqueue.html#aws-resource-batch-jobqueue-returnvalues) and [AWS::Batch::JobDefinition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-batch-jobdefinition.html#aws-resource-batch-jobdefinition-returnvalues), only have the function Ref enabled to return the arn, you can't get any other value of those resources. What you can do is to use the function [Fn::Split](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-split.html) and [Fn::Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html) to obtain their names based on the arn. For example,

1. For the JobQueue, with arn `arn:aws:batch:us-east-1:111122223333:job-queue/HighPriority`, this code will return `HighPriority`.

   ```
   JOB_QUEUE: !Select [1 , !Split ["/", !Select [5, !Split [":", !Ref JobQueue]]]]
   ```
2. For the JobDefinition, with arn `arn:aws:batch:us-east-1:111122223333:job-definition/test-gpu:2`, this code will return `test-gpu`.

   ```
   JOB_DEFINITION: !Select [1 , !Split ["/", !Select [5, !Split [":", !Ref JobDefinition]]]]
   ```

Comment: Thanks Aura, sorry it took so long to say! This did the job perfectly!